# What tool/approach is best to use to document the structure and hierarchy of a SharePoint site collection?

Tags: best-practices

I need to document the structure and hierarchy of a SharePoint site collection. We need to show the Different sub sites, the hierarchy, the lists and libraries in each site, the list columns in case of custom lists, features activated, etc.

What is the best approach to do that? Are some tools that can be used for this? recommended templates?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for static documentation then a quick approach could be to use the Server Explorer within Visual Studio 2010. Just point it to your farm and it will list all the web apps/site cols/sites/lists etc. Also, install [CKS](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex to give you even more information in the treeview. Everything you have mentioned will be in the tree. Then screen shot away.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is able to access all this information.

If your reporting needs are simple enough this should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into Mind Jet Manager 9 with the SharePoint extension.  Perhaps a trial for each is available from the site here
[link text](http://www.mindjet.com/products/mindmanager-extensions/mindmanager-explorer-for-sharepoint/overview)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display your hierarchy on a Web Page, and have it dynamically updated, then I would suggest to look into Web services.

For example, Marc Anderson's SPServices library on Codeplex already offers built-in functions that can help: http://spservices.codeplex.com/